# Android layout not showing properly with RelativeLayout below Gallery?

Tags: android, layout, gallery, android-relativelayout

I have a layout like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollViewHome"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentOuter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >           

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/home_banner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" >
        </Gallery>            
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It will show my Gallery in the middle of screen. There is a blank space above and below Gallery since the image's height is not fit the whole screen. It's OK. Then I want to add 2 TextView below the Gallery:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollViewHome"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentOuter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >           

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/home_banner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" >
        </Gallery>            

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/topHot"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topHotText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/home_segment_home1"
                android:textColor="#8e8e8e"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/watch_all"
                android:textColor="#8e8e8e"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

After add the `<RelativeLayout>`, the blank space above and below Gallery become bigger. And 2 TextView inside `<RelativeLayout>` is not showing. There's still only Gallery on the screen. Why's that? Dis I write something wrong? Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply orientation vertical to Linear Layout in Scroll View. This might be a reason.

Comment: Perfect. You save my day. Can I ask why we should put orientation vertical to Linear Layout? And another problem, now 2 TextView is showing, but they're both align left. I've set 1 of them `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` but why it's not working?

Comment: its the only Layout that arranges its children in a single column or a single row....

Comment: replace the android:layout_width="fill_parent" to be as android:layout_width="wrap_content" in both of your textviews

Answer (score 1):

change your linear Layout to vertical

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentOuter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: You're also right but Siva K give answer first so I'll set his as answer and vote up for you. Thanks. And another problem, now 2 TextView is showing, but they're both align left. I've set 1 of them android:layout_alignParentRight="true" but why it's not working?

Comment: you want to set it vertically or horizontally ?